# Disable register email notification

Tags: users

I have made a deep research over the web and I also tried a lot of alternative solutions, but I didn't find any solution to disable the email notification for new users.

In my User Settings, I have the option "Visitors can create accounts but administrator approval is required" checked, and the option "Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account" not checked.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you look at the function [_user_email_notify()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/_user_mail_notify/6), it checks the variable `'user_mail_' . $op . '_notify'` if it should send an email or not. Assuming that you have disabled email confirmation (otherwise, disabling mail notifications would be weird ;)), the $op is `'register_no_approval_required'`. So the full variable name is `'user_mail_register_no_approval_required_notify'`.

There doesn't seem to be a User Interface for that variable. However, you can set it in your settings.php, adding the following line at the end of settings.php (probably inside sites/default).

```
$conf['user_mail_register_no_approval_required_notify'] = FALSE;
```

You can do the same for other mail notifications too; the other possible `$op` values are listed on the linked page.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is so hard to believe that there is not admin setting.

Comment: Actually, I can see a use-case for preventing emails w/ user confirmation required.  The system emails are pretty limited if you want to send html emails or vary the response by user role, so I can seeing wanting to take over this workflow with Rules & custom emails.  Thanks @Berdir.

Comment: FYI, the 'mailcontrol' module below is this same solution rolled into a simple module.  Don't overlook it.

Comment: You can also set this variable on the database. In the variable table

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Mailcontrol](http://drupal.org/project/mailcontrol) module.

It allows you to turn on/off any standard Drupal mail you wish right from the UI.

> Have full control over the default mails sent by Drupal 7 out of the box.
>
> #### Description
>
> This small module extends original Drupal 7 account settings page with the ability to globally turn ON/OFF all standard mails.
>   By default Drupal 7 provides no option to globally disable the following mails:
>
> - Welcome (new user created by administrator)
> - Welcome (awaiting approval)
> - Welcome (no approval required)
> - Password recovery

Answer (score 5):

In Drupal 8, the the equivalent of [the code given from Berdir for the settings.php file](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/3074/199) is the following one.

```
$config['user.settings']['notify.register_no_approval_required'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this in a custom module to add the settings in a checkbox as it is done in account activation settings.

```
function your_module_form_user_admin_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

  // allow admin to choose if a notification mail is sent to no approval required users
  form['email_no_approval_required']['user_mail_register_no_approval_required_notify'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Notify user when account is created.'),
    '#default_value' => variable_get('user_mail_register_no_approval_required_notify', FALSE),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 7:

You can edit the variable table directly:
name: user_mail_status_activated_notify
value: i:0;

or in your template.php file:

```
if(variable_get('user_mail_status_activated_notify') == 1){
    variable_set('user_mail_status_activated_notify', 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a checkbox to disable at admin/user/user/create.
For me, it's disabled by default.

Comment: Yes, this really is supposed to work, but, I meant, in case of anonymous registration, do not send an automatic email notify.

Comment: @Inunesbr What do you mean with "anonymous registration"?

Comment: @kiamlaluno the visitor who creates an account by itself in "user/register"

Answer (score 1):

**For Drupal 8 following work for me.**

The following code does not send an email after registration.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 *
 * Don't send any mail during registration.
 */
function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if ($message['id'] == 'user_register_no_approval_required' && $message['key'] == 'register_no_approval_required') {
      $message['send'] = FALSE;
      return;
  }
}
```