# How to disable new user registered email to admin

Tags: users

When a new user registers, there's an email sent to the admin in the form:

Subject: Account details for [name] at [site name] (pending admin approval)
Message: [Name] has applied for an account.
[profile URL]

How can I remove this email alert? The reason being, that I've created a customised message triggered by the Apply for role module.
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Drupal are you running?

Comment: Possibly dup of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/disable-register-email-notification?rq=1

Comment: That one seems to refer to the e-mails sent to the registrants, not the site admins.

Answer (score 4):

This email is not configurable via the UI.

You can use [hook_mail_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/7), which will allow you to stop the sending of a message.
So you would create a custom module that does this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_mail_alter().
 */
function MODULE_NAME_mail_alter(&$message) {
  // Stop the default drupal email that goes out to admins when a user
  // registers on the site. An alternative email is sent out via other means.
  if ($message['key'] == 'register_pending_approval_admin') {
    $message['send'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```