# How to deactivate the automatic emails sent to administrator?

Tags: users, emails

Is there any existing module to edit automatic emails sent to admin by Drupal 7? 
Something like [Mail Editor](https://drupal.org/project/mail_edit) to edit the mail templates but not only for those sent to users.

I need to deactivate the automatic email sent to administrator when an user have created an account. I have created a Rule to have details on this new account with tokens and now I do not need the automatic core email anymore.

Thanks for any help. I can not find any solution to this, except this [custom module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31431/how-to-disable-new-user-registered-email-to-admin) and I would prefer a newbie solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable and Install the [Mailcontrol](https://drupal.org/project/mailcontrol) module and then go to `admin/config/people/accounts` turn off the checkbox.

> This small module extends original Drupal 7 account settings page with
>   the ability to globally turn ON/OFF all standard mails.

By default Drupal 7 provides no option to globally disable the following mails:

- Welcome (new user created by administrator)
- Welcome (awaiting approval)
- Welcome (no approval required)
- Password recovery

[image]

Comment: I have tried this module but it will deactivate the email for both user and administrator. So I guess I have to use MailControl to block the notification (user registration pending approval, in my case) and create two new Rules, one for the user (approximately the same email) and one for the admin, with the details expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mailcontrol is not a solution for my problem. I have unchecked the notification for "Welcome (awaiting approval)" and create a Rule with two actions when an user create an account : an email for the user, exactly the same as the core one, and a second email to the admin with details about the new account (by default, you only have an edit URL and the username). I tried to create a new account and Mailcontrol has blocked the Rules actions so I have not received any message. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It works. I only forgot to check at Configuration>People>Account settings, "Who can register accounts?" > Visitors but admin approval is required. I should have unchecked this during my different config tests. Thanks again.