# When user is registered to drupal site ,disable admin approval notification

Tags: users

I want to disable admin approval notification when user is getting registered to a drupal site. I don't want to send notification mail to the admin.

Answer (score 6):

You can disable the administration approval option in configuration page /admin/config/people/accounts of your site.

Otherwise, if you wish to maintain adminstration approval but only disable the email, add the following line at your settings.php:

```
$conf['user_mail_register_no_approval_required_notify'] = FALSE;
```

Links: [Disable register email notification](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/disable-register-email-notification)

Answer (score 1):

According to the question to disable the ADMIN notifikation, the right conf is  $conf['user_mail_register_pending_approval_notify'] = FALSE;