# User Registration Disable Email Verification

Tags: forms, users, emails

The issue is for non admins to only view a particular part of the user section. The current password and email address fields need to be hidden. I've tried the field permissions but that doesnt give an option.

Writing the hook makes sense to hide both the fields but the validation is what I'm having issues with. If I add optional mail or the mail control modules, I'm thinking its going to throw a few other things off.

Comment: The issue is for non admins to only view a particular part of the user section. The current password and email address fields need to be hidden. I've tried the field permissions but that doesnt give an option. Writing the hook makes sense to hide both the fields but the validation is what I'm having issues with. If I add optional mail or the mail control modules, I'm thinking its going to throw a few other things off.

Comment: It seems you've edited this question down to nothing. Care to put something back?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a lot more than just unsetting the field if you want to change the way registration works. Out of the box, Drupal expects a valid email unique address for every user. This is why there are contributed modules for this purpose: it needs a fair amount of code to achieve.

Take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/optional_mail for example.

Comment: i had to remove the question because it had internal code from my company. i apologize. is there a way to completely delete this without getting blocked from using this program?

Comment: You could rephrase the question without pasting code. That should be OK, no?

Answer (score 0):

To disable the user Registration e-mail verification you can use the [mailcontrol](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailcontrol) module.

> Have full control over the default mails sent by Drupal 7 out of the
> box.
>
> ### Description
>
> This small module extends original Drupal 7 account settings page with
> the ability to globally turn ON/OFF all standard mails. By default
> Drupal 7 provides no option to globally disable the following mails:
>
> - Welcome (new user created by administrator)
> - Welcome (awaiting approval)
> - Welcome (no approval required) Password recovery
>
> ### Use cases
>
> This module may come in handy when:
>
> - you don't want to send those emails for some reason
> - or you are sending them through some other means
> - or to get rid of the PHP Mail error message when you’re working on localhost
> - or other development purposes

Also this question have been ask already at - [Disable register email notification](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/disable-register-email-notification)